# Floating div's and webparts left and right

Tags: css, web-part-zone

I've set up a new Page Layout page to replace the Home.aspx of a standard Enterprise Wiki page.

Trying to be a good fellow (and not kill any puppies) I opted to go for div's to achieve my goals instead of tables. My setup is quite plain; two columns dividing the screen approx 60/40 between them, with a blog-like news list on the left and some webpart zones with links etc on the right, preferably floating nicely as the screen size is changed. I did something like this:

```
<div class="FrontPage">
<div class="LeftCol">News list stuff here</div>
<div class="RightCol">
    <div class="Section">
            <div class="IconGfx"><img src="url"></div>Web part zone 1</div>
    <div class="Section">
            <div class="IconGfx"><img src="url"></div>Web part zone 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Well, it's more, but hopefully you get the basic idea. I then styled the classes LeftCol and RightCol with display: inline-block to make them appear side by side, instead of stacked. It works as long as the screen is large enough, but if I shrink the window, the RightCol pops down beneath the LeftCol one.

If I risk a few puppies and do it with a table, I have no such problems. What am I doing wrong on the div styling?

Thanks for all your help!

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Set your FrontPage div to a fixed min-width. this will cause the page to scroll horizontally if made too narrow.

Comment: Ok. How small would it rationally have to be? I'm aiming at desktop/laptop sized screens, with about 1024 in total screen width?

Comment: 1024 probably a good size for most laptops.

Comment: Ok, so then there is the SharePoint chrome to take into account. Would it be possible to make it all float?

Comment: What, ribbon & quick launch? Those are fixed, surely..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html isn't correct. But I suppose that's from simplifying your code?

Have you tried giving the div's width:60% and width:40% in your stylesheet (+ removing all paddings, margins, borders)?

Comment: I see I dropped a closing /div. I tried the 60/40 rule, but then they pop down no matter the screen size. Setting 59/40 allowed me to see it in full screen mode, but as soon as I shrink the size, it pops under.